# Git add new file listed in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I created my `.gitignore` and listed the new files I created, but git still add them when I run my `git add .`

While searching for a solution, I saw a lot of similar question of mine, but for each question people created the `.gitignore` after running the `git add .` command, and the problem was solved with the removing cached files method (`git rm --cached .`), but that didn't work for me since those files were never added before the creation of the `.gitignore` files.

The .gitignore is at the root of my working directory, and looks like that :

```
db.sqlite3
.idea/
venv/
media/
```

And this is what I get when i run `git add .` and `git status`:

```
On branch main
new file:   .idea/vcs.xml
new file:   .idea/workspace.xml
new file:   db.sqlite3
new file:   media/Test.jpg
new file:   media/TestProfilePict.jpg
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Where is your .gitignore? Should be on the level where these file paths make sense

Comment: What does `git check-ignore -v *` command show?

Comment: Make sure your `.gitignore` file is plain-text, ASCII / UTF-8. If it is a UTF-16-LE file it will not work.